# VB - Get the strings inside IN statement

Tags: sql-server, xml, vb.net, view

Working with VB in .Net 2.0 and I want to create a simple program that makes an xml file out of a script(text file) I created with Views like this:

```
USE [Archive-FIRSTVIEW]
GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vABCDEFG]    Script Date: 5/14/2015 8:01:58 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vABCDEFG]
AS
SELECT        dbo.[Document].docGUID, dbo.[Document].accountGUID, dbo.[Document].jobGUID, dbo.[Document].DOC9docID, dbo.[Document].docDate, dbo.[Document].docType, 
                     dbo.[Document].docPages, dbo.[Document].tsCreated
FROM            dbo.AcctLookupKey INNER JOIN
                     dbo.[Document] ON dbo.AcctLookupKey.docGUID = dbo.[Document].docGUID
WHERE        (dbo.AcctLookupKey.ix = 3) AND (dbo.AcctLookupKey.val IN ('ABCDEFG'))


GO
/****** Object:  View [dbo].[vLMNOP]    Script Date: 5/14/2015 8:01:58 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO


CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vLMNOP] AS


SELECT        dbo.[Document].*
FROM            dbo.AcctLookupKey INNER JOIN  dbo.[Document] ON dbo.AcctLookupKey.docGUID = dbo.[Document].docGUID
WHERE        (dbo.AcctLookupKey.ix = 3) 
AND (dbo.AcctLookupKey.val in ('LMNOP','LMNOP (AEIOU)'))
```

I want to retrieve ONLY the text at the end of each WHERE line, for example, the first one to retrieve 'ABCDEFG', and the second one to retrieve both 'LMNOP', 'LMNOP (AEIOU)'

Thanks for any help!

***EDIT:***
I want to create an XML file that looks something like this:

```
<Views Code="FIRSTVIEW">
    <View Name="vABCDEFG">
        <Criteria>ABCDEFG</Criteria>
    </View>
    <View Name="LMNOP">
        <Criteria>LMNOP</Criteria>
        <Criteria>LMNOP (AEIOU)</Criteria>
    </View>
<Views>
```

***EDIT2:***
So far, been able to begin extracting some of the data, just not the way I want it to look. This is before even loading it to an xml.

```
Dim dir As New DirectoryInfo("d:\input")
    Dim sw As New StreamWriter("d:\input\extract.txt")

    For Each fi As FileInfo In dir.GetFiles("views.txt")
        Dim sr As New StreamReader(fi.FullName)
        Dim root As String
        Dim child As String
        Dim substring As String
        While Not sr.EndOfStream
            Dim sLine As String = sr.ReadLine

            If sLine.Contains("USE [") Then
                root = sLine '.Substring(13) - 1
            End If

            If sLine.Contains("CREATE VIEW") Then
                child = sLine '.Substring(19) - 1
            End If

            If sLine.Contains("(''") Then
                substring = sLine
            End If

            sw.WriteLine(root)
            sw.WriteLine(child)
            sw.WriteLine(substring)
        End While
        sr.Close() : sr.Dispose()
    Next
    sw.Flush() : sw.Close() : sw.Dispose()
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do here. Can you please try to clarify?

Comment: @Sean Lange, I'll update my post at the end real quick.

Comment: I would change your question and instead ask "I want to get the strings inside the IN statement"

Comment: Seems like a very fragile and error prone thing to attempt. A quick search found a [sql parser](http://www.sqlparser.com/) that says it creates xml parse trees of sql scripts. Maybe you can do that and mine out the elements you are interested in.

Comment: Were you able to make sense of my answer?  If it helped, please mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very hacky, but it gives you an idea of where to go.  Uses the Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSQL.ScriptDom library to parse the TSQL.  Probably a lot more dependable/flexible than looking for specific strings in your input.

```
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.TransactSql.ScriptDom

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim fragment As TSqlFragment
        Dim parser As New TSql120Parser(True)
        Dim reader As System.IO.StreamReader
        Dim errors As IList(Of ParseError)

        reader = IO.File.OpenText("script.sql")

        fragment = parser.Parse(reader, errors)

        Dim foundIn As Boolean = False
        Dim foundView As Boolean = False
        Dim viewName As String = ""

        For Each tkn As TSqlParserToken In fragment.ScriptTokenStream
            If tkn.TokenType = TSqlTokenType.View Then
                foundView = True
            End If
            If tkn.TokenType = TSqlTokenType.In Then
                foundIn = True
            End If

            'Once you see a View, take everything until you see an As
            If foundView = True And tkn.TokenType = TSqlTokenType.As Then
                Console.WriteLine(viewName.Trim)
                viewName = ""
                foundView = False
            ElseIf foundView = True Then
                viewName += tkn.Text
            End If

            'Once you see an IN, collect the ASCII elements until a right parentheses is encountered.
            If tkn.TokenType = TSqlTokenType.AsciiStringLiteral And foundIn = True Then
                Console.WriteLine(tkn.Text)
            ElseIf tkn.TokenType = TSqlTokenType.RightParenthesis And foundIn = True Then
                'end of the IN condition
                foundIn = False
            End If
        Next

        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs this...
[image]

Comment: Sorry to get back late, and yes, this got me on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!  The ScriptDom library was new to me, and I can see some applications in some things I do, so it was a good exercise for both of us.  Thanks!